# C# ASP MVC: How to create a variable to execute this method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am practicing the demo **MVC 2.0**, but when I create a variable, **Visual Studio** shows an error

> Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Can you help me to resolve the problem? Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult ShowAllProducts()
{
    var allProducts = repository.FindAllProducts;
    return View(allProducts);
}
```

Comment: I would work with some more up-to-date resources: MVC 2.0 is horribly out of date. The current version is 5.0 and works rather differently.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `()` to the end of the line:

```
var allProducts = repository.FindAllProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

FindAllProducts is a method so it requires braces

```
 var allProducts=repository.FindAllProducts();
```